# How to decrease counter without using counter-reset

Tags: css, confluence, css-counter

I've searched for this but I couldn't find anything similar to my problem.

Basically what I have is a counter called `page` and I'm setting up a page counter like this:

`content: "Page " counter(page);` 
 that is displayed like this on screen -> **Page 1**

Everything is working fine, but what I need is to set the page counter to start from **0** instead of **1**

I'm using a Wiki (*confluence*) and I don't have access to where `page` is defined, because it's just a variable meant to be used for CSS counters like before.

I tried to following, but with no luck at all:

`content: "Page " counter(page) - 1;`

`content: "Page " counter(page - 1);`

`content: "Page " calc(counter(page) - 1);`

I've also tried to prepend `counter-reset`:

```
counter-reset: page -1;
content: "Page " counter(page);
```

Now my question is, can I set the counter to start from **0** without using any `counter-reset` property? Or, in the previous example where I actually tried to use the `counter-reset`, did I make any mistake? Am I missing something?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `counter-reset` setting. Your current syntax should make the counter start from -1 and so the first value (assuming increment is by 1) should be 0. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kjsv7z47/) is a sample.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to make it start from 0 (so adding -1 to page) without using counter-reset?

Comment: Yes, you can use a hack (or shall we say non standard way) to do it. But do you really want to use it? If yes, I would post it in answer.

Comment: Yes I'd like to see the answer if possible. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have added the answer but did you mean absolutely no `counter-reset` anywhere in your code? I may have misunderstood you a bit.

Comment: Yes, it seams like I cannot use counter-reset anywhere in the code. Basically i have a space where i can put some custom CSS, and I've added the counter-reset inside body as well as other places, but it doesn't work. Unfortunately I don't have a live demo, as I'm working on some style that needs to be printed as PDF (using confluence built-in tool)

Comment: `counter-reset` is not mandatory though. The first sample in answer should work without the counter reset also because start value if not provided would be assumed as 0.

Comment: Did it work after removing the counter-reset like in my updated answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I wrote a thread in confluence support forum, but apparently what I want to do it's not possible. Thanks anyway for your suggestions! at least now I have a better understanding of CSS counters :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have landed on this page looking for help on **usage of CSS counters with the confluence tool**, please make note of the [comment by Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189904/how-to-decrease-counter-without-using-counter-reset?noredirect=1#comment48532775_30189904):

> I wrote a thread in confluence support forum, but apparently what I want to do it's not possible.

---

Here is one way to make it start from 0 without using `counter-reset: [counter-name] -1`. Basically what we are doing is incrementing the counter only from the second occurrence of the `div class='page'` so that the counter value for the first instance always remains 0.

`counter-reset` does not seem to be a mandatory property<sup>*</sup>. When there is no reset mentioned, 0 is taken as the default value and the below code still works.

<sup>* - Can't find any reference in W3 docs or in MDN that `counter-reset` is optional but browsers seem to support it.</sup>

```css
body {
  counter-reset: page;
}
.page:before {
  content: "Page " counter(page);
}
.page ~ .page {
  counter-increment: page;
}
```

```html
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="page"></div>
```

---

I have posted the above only for a sample and I don't think it is the correct way to do it. The **recommended approach** would be the below where while resetting the counter, we set the start value as `-1`.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: page -1;
}
.page {
  counter-increment: page;
}
.page:before {
  content: "Page " counter(page);
}
```

```html
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="page"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for these examples. I've tried, the problem tho is that seams like counter-reset doesn't work at all. Do you know anything about confluence? maybe it behave in a different way, i don't know..cause both of your solutions should work, but not in my specific case.

Comment: I don't have much idea about confluence but I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. Do you have any demo or link where I can see it live?

Answer (score 0):

Create a var called Time or whatever, it will be your last number showed on your Timer, then after restart check the var and if it is 9 or the number before the restart number, then set the showing number to 0